# Shutdown ExecutorService when at least one Future fails

Tags: java, executorservice

I would like to implement shutting down ExecutorService when at least one Future fails. If this is not possible to be done with ExecutorService please tell me if there is some class that supports this (or maybe I should implement this on my own?). Code:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
public void runCommand(String command) {
        /* This is done in reaction for an event, so we do not know when the new Runnable will be
        submitted... sometimes we can have 10 tasks on the ExecutorService 'queue', sometimes 100 etc. */
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
        logger.info("do something");
        };
        Future<?> runnableFuture = executorService.submit(runnable );
    
        // Somehow 'attach' to ExecutorService and when at least Future<?> from its internal queue is finished and fails -> then shutdown the whole ExecutorService.
    }
```

Comment: Probably the easiest solution is to have your `Runnable` use a try-catch around the actual work, and then simply call `executorService.shutdown()` (or `shutdownNow()`) if an exception is caught. Make sure to rethrow the exception so that the `Future` is still marked as failed.

Comment: Alternatively, pass the executor to a `CompletableFuture`, and check for it completing exceptionally. Something like `compFuture.exceptionally(ex -> executorService.shutdownNow())`